# Display posts from Custom Post Type, group by term, arrange term groups and arrange items within groups by menu order

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, menu-order

I have a Custom Post Type 'my_cpt' and a custom taxonomy 'types' which has several terms, all of which have posts.

I want to do is be able to control both the order of the groups (terms from my custom taxonomy 'types') AND the order of the Items (posts from 'my_cpt' custom post type and the term of the group it is in) within each group by using menu_order in the admin area.

I have this code below (see far bottom) which gets me as far as this:

**Taxonomy term 1**

- Item 1 from taxonomy term 1
- Item 2 from taxonomy term 1

**Taxonomy term 2**

- Item 1 from taxonomy term 2
- Item 2 from taxonomy term 2
- Item 3 from taxonomy term 2

**Taxonomy term 3**

- Item 1 from taxonomy term 3

I can change the order of the groups (Taxonomy term 1, 2, 3 etc) by name if I change:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('surface_bonding_types');
```

to

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('surface_bonding_types', 'orderby=name&order=DESC');
```

So I know the orderby is working for the groups. But I can't see a way to change the order of my Taxonomy terms as there is no 'Order' field as I have with Pages in the admin.

I am completely unable to change the order of the Items within each group. I thought that adding orderby and order parameters to the tax_query array would do the job but it doesn't do anything.

```
                    $custom_terms = get_terms('types');
                    foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                        wp_reset_query();
                        $args = array('post_type' => 'my_cpt',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'types',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                                ),
                            ),
                         );
                    
                         $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                         if($loop->have_posts()) {
                            echo '<h3>'.$custom_term->name.'</h3>';
                            ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php
                                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                                ?>
    
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail' ); ?>
                                            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>                                              
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php
                                endwhile;
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php
                         }
                    }
                
                wp_reset_query();
```

I could what I want to achieve by running multiple wp_query on the page, one for each term but I would end up with 10 almost identical queries on the page. This code feels really close, I just can't quite get the last piece of logic. Any help greatly appreciated.